# How to see django website schema

Tags: python, django

I come from Ruby on rails world. In rails, there is a file called schema.rb. It lists all the tables, columns and their types of the entire rails app.

Is there anyway in django to see the entire database schema at one place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The models for one given app usually lives in the app's "models.py" module. Now Rails and Django might not have the same definition of what's an "app" is. In Django, you have a "project" which consists of one or more (usually more) "apps", and it's considered good practice to try to make apps as independant (hence potentially reusable) as possible, and there are indeed quite a few reusable apps available, so it's pretty uncommon to have *all* of the project's models in a single models.py module.

But anyway: if what you really want is "to see the entire database schema", then the best solution is to ask the database itself, whatever framework you use.